# how to find out each index of a div

Tags: javascript

For example, I have

```
<div class="stick active"></div>
<div class="stick"></div>
<div class="stick"></div>
<div class="stick"></div>
<div class="stick"></div>
```

I need to find out all the indexes from the stick classes so that I can refer to each of them further [0],[1],[2]...

I tried to convert them to an array via **[...]** and via **Array.prototype.slice.call**
but when I try to interact with them, I get "undefined"

Comment: Can you please show the real code you have?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Please see [ask] and create a demo of your code.

Comment: Have you look at [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)?

Answer (score 0):

use this I think it will help you:

for first index:

```
 var x = document.querySelectorAll(".stick"); 
 console.log(x[0])
```

for all:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".stick"); 
console.log(x)
```

Comment: `x` is a very descriptive variable name...

Answer (score 0):

Use `Document.querySelectorAll()` to create a `NodeList`.

querySelectorAll():
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

NodeList:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

```js
const highlightedItems = document.querySelectorAll(".stick");

// access the second node:
console.log(highlightedItems[2].textContent);

// loop through all nodes
for (let i = 0; i < highlightedItems.length; i++) {
  let item = highlightedItems[i];
  console.log( item.id );
}
```

```html
<div class="stick active"></div>
<div class="stick" id="1">A</div>
<div class="stick" id="2">B</div>
<div class="stick" id="3">C</div>
<div class="stick" id="4">D</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to hanle it via `getElementsByClassName`. This returns an HTML collection, not an array, thus you cannot use `indexOf` on it.

Iterating over the elements is the way to go, iterating over `className`, which is a string containing your node's class name, like this:

```js
let stick = document.getElementsByClassName('stick');

for(let i=0; i < stick.length; i++){
  console.log(stick[i]);
}
```